# How do I remove an item in an Array that starts with 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had an array that looked like this:

```
 boxes = ["2 x Apples", "1 x Banana", "", "1 x Pear", "1 x Plum", ""]
```

and when I ran it through this piece of code:

```
var BoxOut = cleanArray(boxes);
var Tex = BoxOut.join("\n");

function cleanArray(actual){
  var newArray = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i<actual.length; i++){
      if (actual[i]){
        newArray.push(actual[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

it returned the following string:

```
 "2 x Apples 1 x Banana 1 x Pear 1 x Plum"
```

It was suggested to put these items in a table and count how many of each item was there. This I have done but because javascript takes the variable var apples; as string, the count was coming out with 11 x apples (concatenation not addition) and I had to declare variable as var apples = 0;

This caused the array to look like this:

```
 ["2 x Apples", "1 x Banana", "0 x Orange", "1 x Pear", "1 x Plum", "0 x Grapes"]
```

and now my string looks like this:

```
 "2 x Apples 1 x Banana 0 x Orange 1 x Pear 1 x Plum 0 x Grapes"
```

Is there a way to adjust the `cleanArray` code so it removes an item in the array that has a 0 in it?

I am relatively new to JS and the answer has to be in pure Javascript as it is all I have to work on.

Thank you in advance

Comment: "that has a 0 in it" --- as a developer you should learn how to express your intentions more clearly. Apparently it's not "has" but "starts with". Then, when you phrase it correctly - the question becomes more clear and (not surprisingly) easy to google for.

Comment: `It was suggested to put these items in a table and count how many of each item was there`?  what table? do you mean a database...

Comment: if so this should be done in the db side itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your if condition to

```
if (actual[i] && actual[i].substring(0, 4) !== "0 x ") {
    newArray.push(actual[i]);
}
```

This only ignores those items that start with "0 x .." and not if a 0 is present anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
if (actual[i] && !actual[i].matches(/0/) ){
    newArray.push(actual[i]);

...
```

That means; whenever there's at least one `0` in it, skip it.

Comment: What if there are 10 apples?

Comment: @Juhana 9 are stolen ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a case in your cleanArray function to check if the string starts with 0. If thats the case you just don't push.
In your if case add:

```
if(!actual[i].startsWith("0")){newArray.push(actual[i]);}
```

That way it only adds the part if it doesn't have a 0 count.

Answer (score -2):

```
var boxes = ["2 x Apples", "1 x Banana", "0 x Orange", "1 x Pear", "1 x Plum", "0 x Grapes"];
        var resultArr = boxes.filter(function (v) {
            return v.indexOf("0") < 0;
        });
```

Comment: what do you do with `10`?